# MySQL Subquery using the same table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to retrieve some ID's from the same table using a sub-query where the column == column.

```
SELECT 
`assemblies`.`id`,
`assemblies`.`type`,
`assemblies`.`champion`,
`assemblies`.`name`,
`assemblies`.`author`,
`assemblies`.`githubLastmod`,
(assemblies.forum IS NOT NULL) AS forumExists,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`champion`) FROM `assemblies` WHERE `githubFolder` = `githubFolder`) AS champions,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes` WHERE `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`) AS votesCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `install_clicks` WHERE `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`) AS installCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `github_clicks` WHERE `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`) AS githubCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `forum_clicks` WHERE `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`) AS forumCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `broken_assemblies` WHERE `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id` AND `ip` = '192.168.10.1') AS isBroken,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes` WHERE `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id` AND `ip` = '192.168.10.1') AS isUpvoted
FROM
`assemblies`
WHERE
`assemblies`.`type` = 'champion'
    AND `assemblies`.`champion` = '84'
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(assemblies.githubLastmod)) > '1419617372'
ORDER BY `votesCount` DESC , `githubLastmod` DESC
```

This part:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`champion`) FROM `assemblies` WHERE `githubFolder` = `githubFolder`) AS champions,
```

This returns the `champion` from all rows, I just want the `champion` if the githubAddress matches.

(I tried to explain this as best as I could haha, if you need more information please comment)

Comment: Are use sure about this part **WHERE `githubFolder` = `githubFolder`**

Comment: I want to match the rows where `githubFolder` equals `githubFolder` (as it is in the same table) and then get the champions of those rows as 1,2,3,4,5,etc

Comment: Can you provide the `assemblies` table sample with 3-4 records. Will help us to understand better

Comment: Ofcourse: http://gyazo.com/52a39c68866f2af8ad2f39a0b83f6915 -- You can have the exact same row where just the champion column is different (and the ID obviously :p). If that's the case I want to get all champion ID's as `champions`

Comment: Thanks !! so it should be  `WHERE githubAddress = githubFolder` that is why `WHERE githubFolder = githubFolder` is getting all records

Comment: Not exactly, the githubAddress is different from the githubFolder. if let's say assembly 1 has a githubFolder column with a value 'https://github.com/' and assembly 2 has that value as well, but assembly 3 has a value of 'http://google.com' it should only return the champion ids of assembly 1 + 2 -- But it is currently returning the champions ids of assembly 1 + 2 + 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to `GROUP BY githubFolder` instead of `WHERE githubFolder = githubFolder`

If we execute this separately , it will serve exactly what we want to achieve here

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('champion') FROM assemblies GROUP BY githubFolder) AS champions
```

But if this will be executed as a sub-query, it will throw error as it returns more than one row

Comment: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row if I use a groupby

Comment: If we could do like `WHERE githubFolder = 'google.com'` then it would return 1 result. But are we trying to get all githubFolder which has atleast more than one occurrence ? please confirm , then we will be able to do this using `count()`

Comment: if it has 1 occurence it should just return 1 champion id. And I'm trying to do this per row, so I don't have the value of what it should match. In that last example I gave you where assembly 1 has a value of 'github.com', assembly 2 has this as well and assembly 3 has a value of 'google.com'. Row 1 (assembly 1) should return 1,2, Row 2 should return 1,2 and row 3 should return 3 -- Where 1,2,3 are champion ID's

Comment: But if we get results like Row 1 and Row 2, we will always get `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: The subquery should return 1,2 because of the GROUP_CONCAT, if I made this too complicated I might just execute 2 queries :p

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() is an **aggregate function** used for 'many to many' relationship . So GROUP BY and ORDER BY will come into play. We dont have 1 unique githubFolder so cannot be done in a subquery

Comment: Ahh so there is no way to do it in 1 query :( -- I would like to thank you anyway for your help and will mark this as answer !

Comment: All right . Just for information  if we don't want same championid  to get repeated we may use  `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT champion `